Algorithm to keep elements at k distance apart while maintaining relative ranking
I have a list of items(id,type,rank). The list is sorted on rank.
The data can be considered random and there is no pattern on percent of a certain type available
Now I want to have items with same type to be atleast k distance apart. Given the randomness of data if that is not possible l, have them as far as possible
The list size is round 1000. Therefore not looking for optimised algo, rather looking for correctness
Note: I would like to keep the list sorted i.e, if given [(1,A,1),(2,A,2),(3,B,3),(4,B,4),(5,C,5)] and k=2 .. I want it to be like [(1,A,1),(3,B,3),(2,A,2),(4,B,4),(5,C,5)]
Similar question: Algorithm to separate items of the same type

It's not entirely clear what you're asking. In the example that you give for a sorted list, your desired result has the elements out of order.
Do you mean that you want the elements of the same type to be sorted by rank?

I want to keep the items with same type k distance apart but also want to retain a bit of sorting as well.

@darkbot Can you define 'a bit of sorting'? Do you mean no item moves more than X from its original position, or do you want the solution that minimizes the number of inversions, or something else?

I think it's worth pointing out that there are inputs where there is no possible answer. For example, the input (1,A,1),(2,A,2) has no answer when k > 1. Whatever algorithm you use, you'll need to decide how you want to detect and respond to cases where there is no possible answer.
With that note, I think your best bet would be to do something like the following:

Split your input array into multiple arrays based on type. For example: the input (1,A,1),(2,B,2),(3,A,3) becomes two arrays. A: (1,A,1),(3,A,3) and B: (2,B,2). I'll call each of these arrays where all the items have the same type a type-array.
Sort each type-array on increasing rank.
Create an output array that starts out as an empty list.
Add items to the output array one-at-a-time, using the following steps once for each item. Stop this loop when all items have been added to the output array:

Look at the output array. Based on the value of k and the last k-1 items in the output array, determine which types could be added to the output array next. Call this set the possible-types.
If the set of possible-types is empty or if the type-arrays associated with the possible-types are all empty, then it's impossible to give an answer for this input, and you should end the algorithm with some reasonable error.
Of the nonempty type-arrays whose type is in the set of possible-types select the longest array. If there are multiple arrays that are tied for longest, break the tie by selecting the array whose first element has the smallest rank. If there's still a tie, compare the ranks of the second item in each array, and then the third item in each array... If there's still a tie after comparing the ranks of all items in the arrays, select the array whose type is alphabetically first.
Pop the first item from the selected array and push it to the end of the output array.



You may want to use a priority queue or two to speed up this algorithm.
